# Having issues trying to use a dictionary to define parameters for Barnsley's Fern

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a rendering of [Barnsley Fern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern) using Python and Pygame, and wanted to include all parameters in a dictionary for easy access, but it doesn't work.

The original code that I have written works as expected. I tried to use a dictionary with keys 'a','b','c','d','e','f' and 'p' for all parameters in the generation of the Barnsley Fern as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern .

When I do run the code, the window freezes and:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/Will's Stuff/Python/Pygame/Bransley'sFernDictionary.py", line 105, in <module>
>     DrawPoint(fernx,ferny)  
>   File "C:/Users/owner/Desktop/Will's Stuff/Python/Pygame/Bransley'sFernDictionary.py", line 47, in DrawPoint
>     pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(screen,cartesianx,cartesiany,white)
> OverflowError: signed short integer is less than minimum
> ```

I expected the Bransley Fern as shown in the Wikipedia article, hich is what has been created in the code without a dictionary, but the window simply crashes after ploting some pixels.

```
import pygame  
import random  
import pygame.gfxdraw  
import math  
import sys  
pygame.init()  

def GeneralAlgorithm(a,b,c,d,e,f,x,y):  
    outputx = a*x + b*y + e  
    outputy = c*x + d*y + f  
    return outputx,outputy  

def GenerateNextPoint(x,y,constants):  
    randompercentage = random.randint(0,100)  
    for n in constants['p']:  
        if randompercentage <= n:  
            i = constants['p'].index(n)  
            print(i)  
            break  
    nextx, nexty = GeneralAlgorithm(constants['a'][i],constants['b'][i],constants['c'][i],constants['d'][i],constants['e'][i],constants['f'][i],x,y)  
    return nextx, nexty  

def DrawPoint(fernx,ferny):  
    cartesianx = int((fernx+2.1820+margin) * (width /(2.1820+2.6558+2*margin)))  
    cartesiany = int((ferny*-1+9.9983+margin) * (height/(9.9983+2*margin)))  
    pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(screen,cartesianx,cartesiany,white)  
    pygame.display.update()  


white = 255,255,255  
background = 20,40,100  

variables1 = {  
    'a':[0   ,0.85 ,0.2  ,-0.15],  
    'b':[0   ,0.04 ,-0.26,0.28 ],  
    'c':[0   ,-0.04,0,23 ,0.26 ],  
    'd':[0.16,0.85 ,0.22 ,0.24 ],  
    'e':[0   ,0    ,0    ,0    ],  
    'f':[0   ,1.6  ,1.6  ,0.44 ],  
    'p':[1   ,86   ,93   ,100  ]  
}  

fernx = 0  
ferny = 0  
width = int(500)  
height = int(500)  
margin = 0.5  

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))  
screen.fill(background)  
pygame.display.update()  

while True:  

    fernx,ferny = GenerateNextPoint(fernx,ferny,variables1)
    DrawPoint(fernx,ferny)
```

Comment: Did you try to print the values of `cartesianx` and `cartesiany`? Do they match the values when calculated manually?

Comment: Min signed short int is –32,768, so i guess your calculated values end up getting too large somehow. Check the values that @kiner_shah mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god I am a fool.

```
variables1 = {  
    'a':[0   ,0.85 ,0.2  ,-0.15],  
    'b':[0   ,0.04 ,-0.26,0.28 ],  
    'c':[0   ,-0.04,0,23 ,0.26 ],  
    'd':[0.16,0.85 ,0.22 ,0.24 ],  
    'e':[0   ,0    ,0    ,0    ],  
    'f':[0   ,1.6  ,1.6  ,0.44 ],  
    'p':[1   ,86   ,93   ,100  ]  
}
```

Look closely at 'c'

```
    'c':[0   ,-0.04,0,23 ,0.26 ],
```

Where a period should be placed, I used a comma.

Just changing that fixed my algorithm.

```
variables1 = {  
    'a':[0   ,0.85 ,0.2  ,-0.15],  
    'b':[0   ,0.04 ,-0.26,0.28 ],  
    'c':[0   ,-0.04,0.23 ,0.26 ],  
    'd':[0.16,0.85 ,0.22 ,0.24 ],  
    'e':[0   ,0    ,0    ,0    ],  
    'f':[0   ,1.6  ,1.6  ,0.44 ],  
    'p':[1   ,86   ,93   ,100  ]  
}
```

The answer is that simple.

FML